# MineCraft Forge How to stop mobs from being invulnerable after hit (Java) 1.10.2

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have made a custom bow that fires really quickly, and I have learned that all mobs are invulnerable for a short period of time after they get hit. This renders my bow pretty much useless. I was wondering if there is any way to change the duration that the mobs are invulnerable for, or even remove it at all.

Code for bow firing method:

```
@Override
    public ActionResult<ItemStack> onItemRightClick(ItemStack stack, World worldIn, EntityPlayer playerIn, EnumHand hand) {
    //  int charge = 1;
    //  charge = ForgeEventFactory.onArrowLoose(stack, worldIn, playerIn, charge, true);
        player123 = playerIn;
        if (!worldIn.isRemote) {
        final ItemArrow itemArrow = (ItemArrow) (Items.ARROW instanceof ItemArrow ? Items.ARROW : Items.ARROW);



        final ItemStack ammo = new ItemStack(Items.ARROW, 1);
        final float arrowVelocity = 1;
        final EntityArrow entityArrow = itemArrow.createArrow(worldIn, ammo, playerIn);
        entityArrow.setAim(playerIn, playerIn.rotationPitch, playerIn.rotationYawHead, 0.0F, arrowVelocity * 3.5F, 0F);
        entityArrow.setDamage(2);
        entityArrow.pickupStatus = EntityArrow.PickupStatus.DISALLOWED;
//      entityArrow.setVelocity(0.2F, 0.1F, 0.2F);
        final ItemStack magicarrow = new ItemStack(TheGalaxyMod.magicarrow, 1);
        EntityLivingBase living = (playerIn);

        if (FastMode.fastmode == 1){
            int index = GetItemSlot(playerIn, magicarrow);
            if (playerIn.inventory.hasItemStack(new ItemStack(TheGalaxyMod.creativequiver)))
            {
                entityArrow.setDamage(5000);
                worldIn.spawnEntityInWorld(entityArrow);
            }
            else if (playerIn.inventory.hasItemStack(new ItemStack(TheGalaxyMod.magicquiver)))
            {
                worldIn.spawnEntityInWorld(entityArrow);
            }
            else if (!(playerIn.inventory.getStackInSlot(index).getItem() == null) && playerIn.inventory.getStackInSlot(index).getItem() == TheGalaxyMod.magicarrow)
            {
                damageItem(playerIn, magicarrow, 1);
                worldIn.spawnEntityInWorld(entityArrow);
                ItemStack stack2 = playerIn.inventory.getStackInSlot(index);
                if(stack2.getItemDamage() > 500)
                {
                    playerIn.inventory.setInventorySlotContents(index, null);
                }
            }
            else if(playerIn.inventory.hasItemStack(ammo) ){
                worldIn.spawnEntityInWorld(entityArrow);
                removeItem(playerIn, ammo);
            }

        }
        else if
        (FastMode.fastmode == 2)
        {
            final ItemArrow itemArrow2 = (ItemArrow) (Items.ARROW instanceof ItemArrow ? Items.ARROW : Items.ARROW);
            final ItemStack ammo2 = new ItemStack(Items.ARROW);
            final float arrowVelocity2 = 1;
            final EntityArrow entityArrow2 = itemArrow2.createArrow(worldIn, ammo2, playerIn);
            entityArrow2.setAim(playerIn, playerIn.rotationPitch, playerIn.rotationYawHead, 0.0F, arrowVelocity2 * 3.5F, 0F);
            entityArrow2.setDamage(2);
            entityArrow2.pickupStatus = EntityArrow.PickupStatus.DISALLOWED;
            int index = GetItemSlot(playerIn, magicarrow);
            if (playerIn.inventory.hasItemStack(new ItemStack(TheGalaxyMod.creativequiver)))
            {
                entityArrow.setDamage(5000);
                worldIn.spawnEntityInWorld(entityArrow);
                entityArrow2.setDamage(5000);
                worldIn.spawnEntityInWorld(entityArrow2);
            }
            else if (playerIn.inventory.hasItemStack(new ItemStack(TheGalaxyMod.magicquiver)))
            {
                worldIn.spawnEntityInWorld(entityArrow);
                worldIn.spawnEntityInWorld(entityArrow2);
            }
            else if (!(playerIn.inventory.getStackInSlot(index).getItem() == null) && playerIn.inventory.getStackInSlot(index).getItem() == TheGalaxyMod.magicarrow)
            {

                damageItem(playerIn, magicarrow, 2);
                worldIn.spawnEntityInWorld(entityArrow);
                worldIn.spawnEntityInWorld(entityArrow2);
                ItemStack stack2 = playerIn.inventory.getStackInSlot(index);
                if(stack2.getItemDamage() > 500)
                {
                    playerIn.inventory.setInventorySlotContents(index, null);
                }
            }
            else if(playerIn.inventory.hasItemStack(ammo) ){
                worldIn.spawnEntityInWorld(entityArrow);
                worldIn.spawnEntityInWorld(entityArrow2);
                removeItem(playerIn, ammo);

            }
        }
        else if
        (FastMode.fastmode == 3)
        {
            entityArrow.setFire(50);
            int index = GetItemSlot(playerIn, magicarrow);
            if (playerIn.inventory.hasItemStack(new ItemStack(TheGalaxyMod.creativequiver)))
            {
                entityArrow.setDamage(5000);
                worldIn.spawnEntityInWorld(entityArrow);
            }
            else if (playerIn.inventory.hasItemStack(new ItemStack(TheGalaxyMod.magicquiver)))
            {
                worldIn.spawnEntityInWorld(entityArrow);

            }
            else if (!(playerIn.inventory.getStackInSlot(index).getItem() == null) && playerIn.inventory.getStackInSlot(index).getItem() == TheGalaxyMod.magicarrow)
            {
                damageItem(playerIn, magicarrow, 2);
                worldIn.spawnEntityInWorld(entityArrow);
                ItemStack stack2 = playerIn.inventory.getStackInSlot(index);
                if(stack2.getItemDamage() > 500)
                {
                    playerIn.inventory.setInventorySlotContents(index, null);
                }
            }
            else if(playerIn.inventory.hasItemStack(ammo) ){
                worldIn.spawnEntityInWorld(entityArrow);
                removeItem(playerIn, ammo);
            }

        }

        }
        return super.onItemRightClick(stack, worldIn, playerIn, hand);

}
```

EDIT:
Solution Found:
Thanks to @Draco18s I have figured out the solution.
All I had to do was add the line

```
entityArrow.hurtResistantTime = 0
```

Comment: Are you sure they're invulnerable? Have you checked what their health is actually doing? What debugging hVe you done?

Comment: Well, the arrows literally fly back at me.

Comment: There is also a forum thread on bukkit about this:[link] https://bukkit.org/threads/how-to-change-mob-invulnerability-duration-after-get-hit.278296/ [link]

Comment: You can set their health and cancel the arrow instead of actually damaging. Hacky, but it works

Comment: Hmmm... That's a good idea! Would you be kind enough to show me an example or point me to a forum thread explaining how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this:

`entityHit.hurtResistantTime = 0;`

Note: exact field name may change depending on Minecraft version and the build number of Forge.

Call it either just before you hurt the entity (bypassing the hurt resistance timers inflicted by all other sources of damage) or after (your damage is ignored if there's a timer, but if it inflicts damage, the *next* source is not ignored due to the timer).  This line needs to be in the *arrow* class.  If you don't have a custom arrow class, now's a good time to make one.

There's no (good) way to conditionally set the timer to 0 based on what the prior damage type was, unfortunately.  If you are on 1.10 or newer, you could use capabilities, although possibly unwieldy.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I was wondering if there's any way to override the EntityArrow class to change that field.

Comment: Yes. Create a new entity class, change what you need to, and spawn it from your own instead of the original. I do this in my [Artifacts mod](https://github.com/Draco18s/Artifacts). It is 1.7 code, but the general principle hasn't changed.

Comment: @TheMCProgrammer Yes. Create a new entity class, replace what you need to, and spawn it from your item instead of the original. I did this in my [Artifacts mod](https://github.com/Draco18s/Artifacts) (look at entities/ for the arrow class and the arrow trap). It's 1.7 code, but the general principle hasn't changed.