# Mob Invincibility after being hit

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

I have created a datapack that allows me to shoot arrows at a firerate of 20 shots/second. However I learned that there is a small invincibility frame of approximately 0.5 second everytime a mob gets hit, rendering my weapon's high firerate completely useless. I have tried setting the {HurtTime} tag to 0s with `execute as @e run data modify entity @s HurtTime set value 0s`, but it won't work. I acknowledge that I can achieve this by using mods but I want to know if there is a way to remove this invincibility frame using in game commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can try multiple ways :

1. With code. You have the same question with code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43788978)
2. Edit your command ([Info](https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/comments/gpnmtk/how_to_remove_mob_invincibilty_frames/)) to :

   ```
   execute as @e run data modify entity @s {HurtTime:0s}
   ```
3. Another code edit: use `entity.setNoDamageTicks(0)` or something like that
4. If nothing works, you should ask it on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I am trying out your command but it is not correct. I think it should be merge instead of modify. However I have tried merging and it still doesn't work. Perhaps the only way is to use codes to make mods which is sad.

Comment: Yes, I know it's difficult for code, but I find more mods that do it than command. Also, maybe you are near to the real command, or maybe it's not the command for your MC version. I suggest you to ask on arqade ;)